# C++ checking elements of strings for equality

Tags: c++, string, character, equality

given a string in this format:

07:05:45PM

I am to convert it to military time.
My idea is to check element 8 of the string for whether it is a 'P' or an 'A' and modify the string accordingly however this expression:

```
if (time[8]  == 'P' );
```

always evaluates as true whether time[8] is an 'A' or a 'P' or even a '7'
why?

Comment: How do you know it's evaluating to true? You're just executing a null statement after the if.

Comment: thanks guys for clearing that up for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have an extra semicolon, right after the `if` statement.